# Symfony2 - access Request object from controller parameter list with multiple parameters

Tags: php, symfony, controller

I am using Symfony 2.4, and according to the Docs, the correct way of retrieving the Request object in the controller is the following:

```
/**
 * @Route("/register/next", name="next_registration_step")
 */
public function nextAction(Request $request = null) {...}
```

This works as expected. However, if I add a parameter to the controller, $request becomes null at runtime:

```
/**
 * @Route("/register/next/{currentStep}", name="next_registration_step")
 */
public function nextAction(Request $request = null, $currentStep = 0) {...}
```

How do I work around this issue without using any older-but-deprecated methods for getting the request?

Note: if possible, a solution that does not involve the Request Stack recently introduced to Symfony 2.4 would be great, as it seems like overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works,

as I think the only difference is that I do not pass `= null` in parameters declaration

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="_demo_hello")
 */
public function helloAction(Request $request, $name)
{
    var_dump($request, $name);die();
```

In Symfony2 controllers it's not a good Idea to declare default value in the method definition - it should be done in routing definition.

In your case:

```
 /*
 *
 * @Route("/register/next/{currentStep}", name="next_registration_step", defaults={"currentStep" = 0})
 */
public function next(Request $request, $currentStep) {...}
```

regards,

Comment: Omitting the default value indeed solves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Note to future readers: as noted in the documentation, there is no problem with using optional parameters: *Making the argument optional, however, is perfectly ok.* (quoted from the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#route-parameters-as-controller-arguments)).

Comment: I'd like to call it by one simple word - bug? I had the same problem with FOSUserBundle with one version of Symfony. Maybe you should try to upgrade your version